# Drag performance in large canvas with many objects

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml

I have a large canvas with many objects on it, which is scrollable (thus why it is so large). 
I have objects I put on the screen that can be clicked and dragged around (for example, a textbox). The object is just capturing the mouse, and calling Canvas.SetLeft() and SetTop() as the OnMouseMoved event is called.

This works fine with smaller canvases, but this really large one with a few thousand objects refreshes the dragged object very slowly... usually with over a second refresh while dragging it. not very user friendly.

I need to improve this buy am not sure how to progress.

One thought I had was, keep a transparent canvas in the foreground that is only the current window size and contains no children. When beginned to drag, move it to this layer until done and move it back to the big one. Lot of effort for yet another hack though...

Update: using perforator, I see the canvas is getting a layout pass performed repeatedly while I drag this object, and this is the slow part. Wondering if there's any way to avoid this...

Comment: Some sort of virtualization would help, e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx might not directly apply to movable items though.

Comment: @H.B.: as long as the moved item is always drawn (regardless of virtualization), it should apply fine.  The slow refresh is probably the canvas repeatedly layout out *all* of its children instead of just those visible.  If it were only doing the latter, there should be a big perf boost.

Comment: I sure wish the canvas had a built-in (optional?) virtualizer for this kinda stuff... I've hit problems trying to use the virtualized canvas in the past, but it might be time to give it another try. Argh.

Comment: Virtualization isn't the sort of thing that's lightweight enough to make optional - that's why the `VirtualizingStackPanel` is a class all of its own.

Comment: Using the adorner layer as your temporary layer might be the way to go...

Comment: I'm using adorders for resizing, and they resize very slowly as well.

Comment: Have you had any progress with this issue I am interested in the same functionality, Would love to here how you resolved it :-)

Comment: @Julian I haven't needed to work on it lately.. probably will again though.

Answer (score 0):

Performance optimisations aren't "hacks."  Big optimisations often involve breaking things apart so that performance can be managed - and that takes effort.

Your suggestion sounds reasonable, but the lag you're getting will likely still happen when you "drop" your item and the canvas refreshes.  Another approach might be to create a "virtualized" canvas that only draws what's currently on-screen.  This is a complex enough task that I'd not attempt to provide a sample here - but it's something that would probably benefit the draw performance of your application throughout.

Comment: I was going down the virtualization route but hit some snags, so instead I focused on using very lightweight items for most of the canvas.. the loading performance is good, and scrolling is fast. So now it's just these dragging items around that seems to be lagging badly. Argh.